# Limit of a 0/0 function

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Let's say we have a function, for example,
$$
f(x) = \frac{x-1}{x^2+2x-3},
$$
and we want to now what is 
$$
\lim_{x \to 1} f(x).
$$
The result is $\frac{1}{4}$.

So there exists a limit as $x \to 1$.

My teacher says that the limit at $x=1$ doesn't exist. How is that? I don't understand it. We know that a limit exists when the one sided limits are the same result.

Thank you!

Comment: Try factoring the denominator. This is probably a homework problem, so look at the numerator for a hint.

Comment: @copper.hat: I completely disagree! In the definition of "$\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)$", $f(1)$ doesn't need to be defined (in fact, in most interesting cases it isn't), and even if it is defined, that value shouldn't be taken into account. Adding "$x \neq 1$" doesn't make any difference whatsoever.

Comment: @HansLundmark: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 13):

It's possible that your teacher was pointing out the fact that *the function doesn't exist* at $x = 1$.  That's different from saying that the *limit doesn't exist* as $x \to 1$.  Notice that by factoring,
$$
f(x) = \frac{x-1}{x^2 + 2x - 3} = \frac{x-1}{(x-1)(x+3)}
$$

As long as we are considering $x \ne 1$, the last expression simplifies:
$$
\frac{x-1}{(x-1)(x+3)} = \frac{1}{x+3}.
$$
In other words, for any $x$ *other than exactly* $1$,
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x+3}.
$$
This helps understand what happens as $x$ gets ever closer to $1$:  $f(x)$ gets ever closer to
$$
\frac{1}{(1) + 3} = \frac{1}{4}.
$$

Comment: The word '_exactly_' unnecessary.

Comment: @CiaPan: What about the word '*is*'?

Comment: @NikolajK that depends on what *'is'* is.

Comment: @Yakk: It's equivalent to equivalence in univalent foundations.

Answer (score 10):

Your teacher is not correct. There are two easy ways to do this problem. The first is by factoring the denomiator:

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x-1}{(x-1)(x+3)}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{x+3}=\frac{1}{4}$$

The second is by using L'Hospital's rule, which is a useful identity in limits. By [L'Hospital's rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html), we know that

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x-1}{x^2+2x-3}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{2x+2}=\frac{1}{4}$$

This limit exists, because it is simply a discontinuity in the function, but it is a discontinuity at a single point. When we have certain indeterminate forms in limits, we may apply L'Hospital's rule, which allows us to better compute the limit.

L'Hospital's rule states that, in certain indeterminate forms:

$$\lim_{x\to n}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to n}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

---

It is worth clearing up a particular misconception that seems to have arisen. For $$f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x^2+2x-3}$$ we cannot compute the *value* of $f(1)$, because this results in an indeterminate form. However, the *limit* exists, because there is simply a local discontinuity at a single point in an otherwise continuous function.

Comment: A third alternative, to whoever may care, is to note that the limit if $\dfrac 1{f'(1)}$, where $f(x)=x^2+2x-3$.

Comment: To justify the use of l'Hospital, you also need to point out that $g' \neq 0$ in a punctured neighbourhood of the point in question.

Comment: A hard requirement of the usability of l'Hôpital's rule is that the resulting "right-hand-size" is exists. But I guess that's what Hans is saying in more fancy terms?

Comment: @rubenvb: No, it's not enough that $\lim f/g$ is of type $0/0$ and that $\lim f'/g'$ exists. There are examples which show this. You really need $g'$ to be nonzero near the point. (Those examples are a bit artificial to be honest, but still...)

Comment: @Hans $g'$ can be zero if $f'$ is zero, because you just have another L'Hospital's case and take $f''/g''$ Otherwise, just compute the limit normally.

Comment: That's not at all what I'm talking about. The problem is if $g'$ has infinitely many zeroes which accumulate at the point where you're taking the limit.

Comment: See [this paper by Boas](http://www.maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/classroom-capsules-and-notes/counterexamples-to-lh-pitals-rule). (It's mainly about the case $x \to \infty$, but the principle is the same.)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what your teacher means exactly. Limits are defined when $x$ *tends* to some number, or infinity. Not when $x$ *is* this number.

The value that the function takes at the limit poit is irrelevant (to compute the limit). In fact, in most high school limit exercises, the function is not defined at the point that $x$ tends to.